ZKsync deployment error: server returned an error response: error code 3: Failed to serialize transaction: toAddressIsNull
When deploying my smart contract, using Forge, to ZKsync, I used the following command:
forge create src/RebaseTokenPool.sol:RebaseTokenPool --rpc-url ${ZKSYNC_SEPOLIA_RPC_URL} --account updraft --constructor-args ${ZKSYNC_REBASE_TOKEN_ADDRESS} "[]" ${ZKSYNC_RNM_PROXY_ADDRESS} ${ZKSYNC_ROUTER} --legacy --zksync

And got the following error message
Error: server returned an error response: error code 3: Failed to serialize transaction: toAddressIsNull
I have tried on Sepolia (and switched my RPC URL) and it deployed fine.

Despite the ZKsync documentation seeming to imply that the --zksync flag needing to be last, this issue arose due to the flag --constructor-args needing to be last:
forge create src/RebaseTokenPool.sol:RebaseTokenPool --rpc-url ${ZKSYNC_SEPOLIA_RPC_URL} --account updraft --legacy --zksync --constructor-args ${ZKSYNC_REBASE_TOKEN_ADDRESS} "[]" ${ZKSYNC_RNM_PROXY_ADDRESS} ${ZKSYNC_ROUTER)

